# Creating the coordinates for a 3 dimensional cube in 1 unit blocks

Tags: sql, rotational-matrices

This a weird question, but it poses an interesting challenge; I have been looking at the old concept for the million dollar HTML matrix (1,000 x 1,000) and was more interested in the concept of a larger cube [like the body of Rubik's cube but without axes] and trying to figure out the way to do it in SQL so that they are ordered from the center.

The center block would be 0,0,0 and then there would be the need to program the coordinates of the blocks surrounding it (-1,0,0; -1,-1,0; and so on and so forth) expanding essentially one level/layer upon layer such that the jump from the first core block to the second cube surrounding it is composed of 26 blocks and their coordinates, but I am thinking that I can generate 27 and then eliminate the ones already in the repository table.

I think I am onto something right there, but the key is that I would love to have them arranged in another table in order such that you could essentially jump to the next block in the cube by touching it, almost like a three dimensional spiral.

Any suggestions would be great and I think I am just going to mess with the concept of creating nested cubes for now, which is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: I solved it one way, but would love to revise it to do it in a better order

Answer (score 0):

declare @start int = 0, @low int

declare @coord table(Coord int IDENTITY(1,1), x int, y int, z int)
declare @coord2 table(x int, y int, z int)
declare @dimensions table (pos int)

while @start <= 3
begin
    select @low = @start * -1

```
delete from @coord2
delete from @dimensions

while @low <= @start
begin
    insert into @dimensions select @low
    select @low = @low + 1
end

insert into @coord (x,y,z)
select * from (select d.pos as x, e.pos as y, f.pos as z from @dimensions d cross join @dimensions e cross join @dimensions f) as a 
where not exists (select * from @coord c WHERE a.x = c.x and a.y = c.y and a.z = c.z)

select @start = @start + 1
```

end

select * from @coord